# Qt linking a QTreeView and a QTableView

Tags: qt

In my app I have two views one is a QTreeView that displays a tree of assemblies.  Assemblies can have other assemblies and parts as children.  The other view is a list of parts in a QTableView.

What I'm trying to do is: when a prt is selected in the assembly tree (parts have no children) I'd like the part to be highlighted in the parts tableview.

This is what I have so far ... in the click handler for the treeview I get the ItemModel and then the part number.

```
QAbstractItemModel *model = asmview->model();
QString partno = model-> index(index.row(), 0, index.parent()).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

bool hasch = model->hasChildren(index);

if (hasch){
  qDebug() << "has children" ;
} else {
  qDebug() << "has no children" ;

  // go find the partnumber in the other grid
  int idx;
  idx = partsview->getItemNoForPartNo(partno);
```

that function just iterates through the list of parts until the correct one is found then returns with the index or -1 if not found.

This is where I get stuck.  I haven't yet found a way to set the current index / selection of the parts table view without compile errors.  These, for example, don't compile:

```
if (idx >= 0){
  // partsview->setCurrentIndex(idx);
  partsview->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(idx);
```

How should this be done?

Comment: Maybe try to use `QItemSelectionModel::select()` function instead? It will select/deselect your view's items.

Comment: @vahancho I'll take another look at that - I did try, but I was struggling to create a QModelIndex from an integer.  (Can you tell I'm new to Qt :)  )

Comment: You cannot create a model index from an arbitrary integers. You can do that only if you know the row and column numbers. In that case you need to use QAbstractItemModel::index() function.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I've got it :D

setCurrentIndex does work if I use a QModelIndex as an argumant, not a int as I was doing.

I make the QMoelIndex as midx in the code below.

```
if (!hasch) {
    // go find the partnumber in the other grid
    int idx = partsview->getItemNoForPartNo(partno);
    QAbstractItemModel *itemmodel = partsview->model();

    if (idx >= 0) {
        QModelIndex midx = itemmodel->index(idx, 0, QModelIndex());
        partsview->setCurrentIndex(midx);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions, it helped.